# How to use batch fetch in hibernate with child tabes?

Tags: hibernate

I have a table user which has 100 records.

I have child table called user roles with 200 records.(2 for each user).

If i Get all the users then 100 queries run.

I use   List userList = session.createCriteria(User.class).list();

Is there a way to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you described is known as n+1 selects problem.

Hiberante provides few different ways to handle it. On of them is to set fetch mode to EAGER for the relationship, that causes the problem.
Assuming one-to-many mapping between table User and table UserRoles is called "userRoles":

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("userRoles", FetchMode.EAGER);
List userList = criteria.list();
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem again 100 queries run with User table outer join user roles. Also that eager join is shown as deprecated.public static final FetchMode DEFAULT = new FetchMode("DEFAULT");

 public static final FetchMode JOIN = new FetchMode("JOIN");

 public static final FetchMode SELECT = new FetchMode("SELECT");

 /** deprecated */
 public static final FetchMode LAZY = SELECT;

 /** deprecated */
 public static final FetchMode EAGER = JOIN;

Comment: Indeed you should use FetchMode.JOIN instead of FetchMode.EAGER.

Comment: Can you provide some more info: how your User and UserRoles entities look like? And how these 100 queries look like?

Comment: User.java  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
 @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
 private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

Comment: UserRole.java @AssociationOverrides({
 @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.user", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")),
 @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.role", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")) })